# Authorization when user details are remembered by the browser

Tags: c#, windows-phone, dropbox, dropnet

I'm building WP7 application using DropNet.
I have successfully managed to log in and authorize the app (using WebBrowser control) and this works ok.
The problem is when user checks 'remember me' on the drop box login screen - an obvious thing to do. When I run this application again then browser redirects to a page saying something like 'you have already authorized this application'. Nothing happens until I click the Continue/OK button on the page. The token is not valid until I click this button.

Why is this happening this way? Shouldn't it authorize the token on entering the authorization page so it would support user-free loging in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you only do the OAuth login/auth stuff the first time he/she uses your app.  Once they are authorized, you'll have an "access token" that you should save somewhere.

The next time the user runs your application, don't do any of the OAuth steps.  Just load up the access token (sometimes called the "user token" in the DropNet docs) and start making real API requests.

```
new DropNetClient(appKey, appSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
```

Comment: Thank Kannan. I have tried this few times and it didn't work. It returned a 'Unathorized' respose when using the api. The problem was that I have been caching user token at the wrong place. I used GetTokenAsync and I should use GetAccessTokenAsync - the last step of authorization. Now it works as it should.

Answer (score 3):

I have come across this issue; the problem was solved by setting

```
 _dropNetClient.UseSandbox = true;
```

where `_dropNetClient`  is an instance of `DropNetClient`